# add a space between two templated variables, angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following div. I am trying to add a space between two templated variables, but the single quotes keep showing up on the screen:

```
<b class="stylefont" ng-click="ctrl.display(1)">
   {{ctrl.car}} + ' ' + {{ctrl.car2}}
</b>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply do the following :

```
<b class="stylefont" ng-click="ctrl.display(1)">
   {{ctrl.car + ' ' + ctrl.car2}}
</b>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **'& nbsp;'** character ([non-breaking space](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp))

```
<b class="stylefont" ng-click="ctrl.display(1)">
   {{ctrl.car}}&nbsp;{{ctrl.car2}}
</b>
```